# SAP Cloud Connector - Failed to start component

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, maven, tomcat, sap-cloud-connector

we attempted to upgrade the SAP Cloud Connector from version 2.15.2 to 2.16.1 but after the upgrade, the SAP Cloc stopped listening to port 8443 and it was impossible to log into GUI. In ljs_trace.log we get this error:

```
2023-12-13 07:49:48,179 +0000#INFO#com.sap.scc.tomcat#localhost-startStop-1#          #PropertyDigester.getProperty(catalina.base)
2023-12-13 07:49:51,971 +0000#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase#Catalina-startStop-1#          #A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:891)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:792)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/core/connectivity/tunnel/api/mapping/MappingResolver
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:853)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2344)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:817)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1150)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2725)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1999)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:285)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:138)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:329)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.core.connectivity.tunnel.api.mapping.MappingResolver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1338)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1150)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
2023-12-13 07:49:51,973 +0000#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase#CloudConnectorMainThread#          #A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
```

Is there anyone that would be able to help?

We tried uninstalling the SAP Cloc and setting it up from scratch, we have the HA setup master/shadow, and we are following the official SAP note for upgrading, so shadow upgrade is first but we cannot move forward since shadow starts with the error.